# How to divide N numbers into N/2 groups (2 numbers each group) such that the sum of diffrence between the 2 numbers in each group is minmal?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

## General Problem Description

Hi, it is actually a special **assignment problem**( check wiki if interested). Suppose I have 10 agents denoted as *A1, A2, ... A10* and I need them to work in pairs. While, according to previous experience, I know the working efficiency of each two-agent pair so that I have an efficiency matrix shown as follows whose *( i, j )* element represents the working efficiency of agent pair *( Ai, Aj )*. Hence, we know it should be a symmetric matrix, which means *E( i, j )=E( j, i )* and *E( i, i )* should be 0. Now, I need divide these 10 agents into 5 groups such that the overall (sum) efficiency is maximal.

E =

```
 0    25    28    23    39    77    56    58    85    41
25     0    18    77    32    52    69    59    47    18
28    18     0    20    55    75    63    38     5    56
23    77    20     0    59    76    24    82    68    64
39    32    55    59     0    49    70    28    42    31
77    52    75    76    49     0    33    84    50    29
56    69    63    24    70    33     0    15    49    83
58    59    38    82    28    84    15     0    68    40
85    47     5    68    42    50    49    68     0    56
41    18    56    64    31    29    83    40    56     0
```

## N.B.

1. From the matrix view of this problem, I need pick 5 elements from above matrix such that none of them share a same index with others. ( if you pick *E( 2, 3 )*, then you cannot pick any elments with index containing 2 or 3 since *A2* and *A3* are assigned to work. In other words, you cannot pick any elements from the 2nd, 3rd row and 2nd, 3rd column.)
2. The title of this problem is an equivalent problem to the special assignment problem mentinoned above.
3. You may find the [Hungarian(munkres) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) helpful! [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20328-munkres-assignment-algorithm) is the **matlab** code.
4. Another view of this problem is to solve a normal assignment problem, but we need to find a solution whose elements are symmetrically distributed about the diagonal.
5. Directly applying Hungarian(munkres) algorithm to the symmetric efficiency matrix does not always work. Sometimes it will give asymmetric permutations e.g.

E =

```
 0    30    63    32    20    40
30     0    67    84    75    63
63    67     0    37    79    88
32    84    37     0    43    59
20    75    79    43     0    56
40    63    88    59    56     0
```

The optimal solution is:

assignment =

```
 0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved as [weighted maximum matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs), where:

```
G = (V,E,w)
V = { all numbers } 
E = { (v,u) | v,u in V, v!=u }
w(u,v) = -|u-v|
```

The solution to maximum matching will pair all your vertices (numbers), such that sum of:  `sum { -|u-v| : u,v paired }` is maximum, which means `sum { |u-v| : u,v paired` is minimum.

Comment: may be I am under-thinking this but should not be enough to sort the numbers (asc or desc) and use consequenced pairs as groups .... for example `{ 13,9,5,3,2,1 } -> { 13,9 },{ 5,3 },{ 2,1 }` ? .. but if the effectiveness is nonlinear than you're right

Comment: @amit, thank you so much for your answer! by your hint, I find [Edmonds' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs) pefectly solves my question.